# delay populating fields until both dropdowns are selected

Tags: javascript

[Here is my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrFent/ecv9sbwr/).

I have two dropdowns with different family relationships. When selected, they populate in some lines of text below the dropdowns. I would like to delay the population of the text until both dropdowns are selected.

```js
function functionOne() {

  var e = document.getElementById("dropdown_1");
  var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById('first').textContent = strUser + (strUser ? "'s" : "");
  document.getElementById('fourth').textContent = strUser;
}
functionOne()

document.getElementById("dropdown_1").onchange = functionOne;

function functionTwo() {

  var e = document.getElementById("dropdown_2");
  var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  var strUser2 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById('second').textContent = strUser;
  document.getElementById('third').textContent = strUser2 + (strUser2 ? "'s" : "");
}
functionTwo()

document.getElementById("dropdown_2").onchange = functionTwo;
```

```css
span#first,
span#second,
span#third,
span#fourth {
  min-width: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
  height: 18px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
My
<select class="text_select" id="dropdown_1" name="dropdown_1">
  <option value="">- Select -</option>
  <option value="Father">Father's</option>
  <option value="Mother">Mother's</option>
  <option value="Sister">Sister's</option>
  <option value="Brother">Brother's</option>
  <option value="Husband">Husband's</option>
  <option value="Wife">Wife's</option>
  <option value="Son">Son's</option>
  <option value="Daughter">Daughter's</option>
  <option value="Grandfather">Grandfather's</option>
  <option value="Grandmother">Grandmother's</option>
  <option value="Aunt">Aunt's</option>
  <option value="Uncle">Uncle's</option>
  <option value="Cousin">Cousin's</option>
  <option value="Father-in-Law">Father-in-Law's</option>
  <option value="Mother-in-Law">Mother-in-Law's</option>
  <option value="Sister-in-Law">Sister-in-Law's</option>
  <option value="Brother-in-Law">Brother-in-Law's</option>
  <option value="Niece">Niece's</option>
  <option value="Nephew">Nephew's</option>
  <option value="Grandson">Grandson's</option>
  <option value="Granddaughter">Granddaughter's</option>
  <option value="Great-Aunt">Great-Aunt's</option>
  <option value="Great-Uncle">Great-Uncle's</option>

</select>

<select class="text_select" id="dropdown_2" name="dropdown_2">
  <option value="">- Select -</option>
  <option value="Father">Father</option>
  <option value="Mother">Mother</option>
  <option value="Sister">Sister</option>
  <option value="Brother">Brother</option>
  <option value="Husband">Husband</option>
  <option value="Wife">Wife</option>
  <option value="Son">Son</option>
  <option value="Daughter">Daughter</option>
  <option value="Grandfather">Grandfather</option>
  <option value="Grandmother">Grandmother</option>
  <option value="Aunt">Aunt</option>
  <option value="Uncle">Uncle</option>
  <option value="Cousin">Cousin</option>
  <option value="Father-in-Law">Father-in-Law</option>
  <option value="Mother-in-Law">Mother-in-Law</option>
  <option value="Sister-in-Law">Sister-in-Law</option>
  <option value="Brother-in-Law">Brother-in-Law</option>
  <option value="Niece">Niece</option>
  <option value="Nephew">Nephew</option>
  <option value="Grandson">Grandson</option>
  <option value="Granddaughter">Granddaughter</option>
  <option value="Great-Aunt">Great-Aunt</option>
  <option value="Great-Uncle">Great-Uncle</option>
</select>

<br /><br /><br />
<label class="row_1">My <span id="first"></span> <span id="second"></span></label>
<br />
<label class="row_2">My <span id="third"></span> <span id="fourth"></span></label>
```

Answer (score 3):

Select each `select` beforehand, and if either `selectedIndex` is `0`, return immediately, to ensure that both must have a `selectedIndex` other than `0` to proceed to populate the other elements. Also, you can now combine both listener functions into one, because they now do the exact same thing:

```js
var e1 = document.getElementById("dropdown_1");
var e2 = document.getElementById("dropdown_2");

function populate() {
  if (e1.selectedIndex === 0 || e2.selectedIndex === 0) return;

  var strUser1 = e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById('first').textContent = strUser1 + "'s'";
  document.getElementById('fourth').textContent = strUser1;

  var strUser2 = e2.options[e2.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById('second').textContent = strUser2;
  document.getElementById('third').textContent = strUser2 + "'s'";
}

document.getElementById("dropdown_1").onchange = populate;
document.getElementById("dropdown_2").onchange = populate;
```

```css
span#first,
span#second,
span#third,
span#fourth {
  min-width: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
  height: 18px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
My
<select class="text_select" id="dropdown_1" name="dropdown_1">
  <option value="">- Select -</option>
  <option value="Father">Father's</option>
  <option value="Mother">Mother's</option>
  <option value="Sister">Sister's</option>
  <option value="Brother">Brother's</option>
  <option value="Husband">Husband's</option>
  <option value="Wife">Wife's</option>
  <option value="Son">Son's</option>
  <option value="Daughter">Daughter's</option>
  <option value="Grandfather">Grandfather's</option>
  <option value="Grandmother">Grandmother's</option>
  <option value="Aunt">Aunt's</option>
  <option value="Uncle">Uncle's</option>
  <option value="Cousin">Cousin's</option>
  <option value="Father-in-Law">Father-in-Law's</option>
  <option value="Mother-in-Law">Mother-in-Law's</option>
  <option value="Sister-in-Law">Sister-in-Law's</option>
  <option value="Brother-in-Law">Brother-in-Law's</option>
  <option value="Niece">Niece's</option>
  <option value="Nephew">Nephew's</option>
  <option value="Grandson">Grandson's</option>
  <option value="Granddaughter">Granddaughter's</option>
  <option value="Great-Aunt">Great-Aunt's</option>
  <option value="Great-Uncle">Great-Uncle's</option>

</select>

<select class="text_select" id="dropdown_2" name="dropdown_2">
  <option value="">- Select -</option>
  <option value="Father">Father</option>
  <option value="Mother">Mother</option>
  <option value="Sister">Sister</option>
  <option value="Brother">Brother</option>
  <option value="Husband">Husband</option>
  <option value="Wife">Wife</option>
  <option value="Son">Son</option>
  <option value="Daughter">Daughter</option>
  <option value="Grandfather">Grandfather</option>
  <option value="Grandmother">Grandmother</option>
  <option value="Aunt">Aunt</option>
  <option value="Uncle">Uncle</option>
  <option value="Cousin">Cousin</option>
  <option value="Father-in-Law">Father-in-Law</option>
  <option value="Mother-in-Law">Mother-in-Law</option>
  <option value="Sister-in-Law">Sister-in-Law</option>
  <option value="Brother-in-Law">Brother-in-Law</option>
  <option value="Niece">Niece</option>
  <option value="Nephew">Nephew</option>
  <option value="Grandson">Grandson</option>
  <option value="Granddaughter">Granddaughter</option>
  <option value="Great-Aunt">Great-Aunt</option>
  <option value="Great-Uncle">Great-Uncle</option>
</select>

<br /><br /><br />
<label class="row_1">My <span id="first"></span> <span id="second"></span></label>
<br />
<label class="row_2">My <span id="third"></span> <span id="fourth"></span></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare strUser & strUser2 variable outside the fuction. In that case both the functions will have access to these variables.

Also create a function which will be called if both the variables have value in them

```js
var strUser = '',
  strUser2 = '';

function functionOne() {

  var e = document.getElementById("dropdown_1");
  strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  if (strUser !== '' && strUser2 !== '') {
    populateFields()

  }
}
functionOne()

document.getElementById("dropdown_1").onchange = functionOne;

function functionTwo() {

  var e = document.getElementById("dropdown_2");
  strUser2 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  if (strUser !== '' && strUser2 !== '') {
    populateFields()

  }
}
functionTwo()

document.getElementById("dropdown_2").onchange = functionTwo;
// a new function which will be triggered if the 
//variables value is not empty string
function populateFields() {

  document.getElementById('first').textContent = strUser + (strUser ? "'s" : "");
  document.getElementById('fourth').textContent = strUser;

  document.getElementById('second').textContent = strUser;
  document.getElementById('third').textContent = strUser2 + (strUser2 ? "'s" : "");


}
```

```css
span#first,
span#second,
span#third,
span#fourth {
  min-width: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
  height: 18px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
My
<select class="text_select" id="dropdown_1" name="dropdown_1">
  <option value="">- Select -</option>
  <option value="Father">Father's</option>
  <option value="Mother">Mother's</option>
  <option value="Sister">Sister's</option>
  <option value="Brother">Brother's</option>
  <option value="Husband">Husband's</option>
  <option value="Wife">Wife's</option>
  <option value="Son">Son's</option>
  <option value="Daughter">Daughter's</option>
  <option value="Grandfather">Grandfather's</option>
  <option value="Grandmother">Grandmother's</option>
  <option value="Aunt">Aunt's</option>
  <option value="Uncle">Uncle's</option>
  <option value="Cousin">Cousin's</option>
  <option value="Father-in-Law">Father-in-Law's</option>
  <option value="Mother-in-Law">Mother-in-Law's</option>
  <option value="Sister-in-Law">Sister-in-Law's</option>
  <option value="Brother-in-Law">Brother-in-Law's</option>
  <option value="Niece">Niece's</option>
  <option value="Nephew">Nephew's</option>
  <option value="Grandson">Grandson's</option>
  <option value="Granddaughter">Granddaughter's</option>
  <option value="Great-Aunt">Great-Aunt's</option>
  <option value="Great-Uncle">Great-Uncle's</option>

</select>

<select class="text_select" id="dropdown_2" name="dropdown_2">
  <option value="">- Select -</option>
  <option value="Father">Father</option>
  <option value="Mother">Mother</option>
  <option value="Sister">Sister</option>
  <option value="Brother">Brother</option>
  <option value="Husband">Husband</option>
  <option value="Wife">Wife</option>
  <option value="Son">Son</option>
  <option value="Daughter">Daughter</option>
  <option value="Grandfather">Grandfather</option>
  <option value="Grandmother">Grandmother</option>
  <option value="Aunt">Aunt</option>
  <option value="Uncle">Uncle</option>
  <option value="Cousin">Cousin</option>
  <option value="Father-in-Law">Father-in-Law</option>
  <option value="Mother-in-Law">Mother-in-Law</option>
  <option value="Sister-in-Law">Sister-in-Law</option>
  <option value="Brother-in-Law">Brother-in-Law</option>
  <option value="Niece">Niece</option>
  <option value="Nephew">Nephew</option>
  <option value="Grandson">Grandson</option>
  <option value="Granddaughter">Granddaughter</option>
  <option value="Great-Aunt">Great-Aunt</option>
  <option value="Great-Uncle">Great-Uncle</option>
</select>

<br /><br /><br />
<label class="row_1">My <span id="first"></span> <span id="second"></span></label>
<br />
<label class="row_2">My <span id="third"></span> <span id="fourth"></span></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this.

```js
function functionOne(strUser){
  document.getElementById('first').textContent = strUser+(strUser ? "'s" : "");
  document.getElementById('fourth').textContent = strUser;
}



function functionTwo(strUser, strUser2){
  document.getElementById('second').textContent = strUser;
  document.getElementById('third').textContent = strUser2+(strUser2 ? "'s" : "");
}

var drp1 = document.getElementById("dropdown_1");
var drp2 = document.getElementById("dropdown_2");

function checker(){
    var strUser = drp1.options[drp1.selectedIndex].value;
      var strUser2 = drp2.options[drp2.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(strUser, strUser2);
    if(strUser && strUser2){
        functionOne(strUser);
      functionTwo(strUser, strUser2);
    }
}

document.getElementById("dropdown_1").onchange = checker;
document.getElementById("dropdown_2").onchange = checker;
```

Your html and css remain untouched.

What I did is add **checker** function and rename a few variable's name to more appropriate.

Function **checker** is run everytime a dropdown is changed.
It gets the selected option for each dropdown, check if both has value and run your functions **functionOne** and **functionTwo**.

Hope this helps.